# Hard Coding Components on a Client Specific Websites

Tags: templates, page-template, frontpage

This is something I have been meaning to ask for a while to get some feedback. If you are creating theme template files for a client and you know what needs to go where e.g. buttons, logo, component background image, section headings on homepage etc etc, what are your views on coding some of these components into the template?

I am just trying to gauge the difference between building out a theme for public download in comparison to building out a theme for a specific project. If I know the feature the client wants would it be the right thing to do to code them direct into the templates rather than creating widget areas and custom widgets?

All your thoughts are welcome as I am still relatively new to WordPress and just want to gather other users thoughts :)

Craig

Comment: Just to add, this is not referencing post types and pages all of those will be handled in the usual way and with custom post types when needed. This is simply in regard to a background image that wont change and logos that wont change.

Comment: Technically off-topic here but I'm chipping in with my two cents anyway.  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you should ask before deciding if specific content/code belongs in the template file or the content editor is "Will the client want easy access to update this content?" or perhaps "Is this information EVER going to change?".

Personally, I prefer to keep the M in CMS and strive to always have easily managed content.  Often, this means extra steps creating custom metaboxes to expose individual sections of structured content to the page editor.  Elliot Condon's ACF plugin can help you see what's possible in that respect though this functionality is possible w/o the plugin.  These extra steps usually require a few extra hours of coding and testing.  It always produces a happy client, however.

Think about the first time you were tasked with editing a simple bit of text on a WordPress site and when you opened that page to edit it, the content editor was empty.  How familiar is your client with HTML and PHP?  Do you think they should be required to hunt down a page template, scan the code for the piece to edit the content, etc?

Cost and client expectations must also be considered.  Did you bid the job nice and low so you could get the work or did you communicate the value you would deliver with an easily maintained site, justifying your much higher project cost?

Comment: Thank you for this answer it has cleared a few things up in my mind! I am familiar with custom post types and fields so I think my next step is possibly adding some fields to the customizer for particular sections were I know there needs to be text but it allows the client to go in and edit that text themselves.

Answer (score 0):

A common technique for this type of customization is to use a child theme. Even when building a custom theme it can be useful to put generic or generalized layout and style into a theme of it's own, then use a child theme to make site-specific adjustments. This way you can make fixes and tweaks to the parent theme and allow the site owner to make changes to the child theme without losing your code.

@see: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes